# One-Sample Test for differences between questionnaire-answers

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, z-test

For a rather large sample (>800 participants) I have answers from a questionnaire, containing multiple Yes/No-Questions. 
What I want to find out is, if the proportions of yes & no's differ between each question.

For that I thought about using multiple one-sample z-tests. Meaning, I would calculate the proportions of yes's for each question and then use 6 z-tests to test if the proportions for Question1 differ from Question2s proportions, if Q1 differs from Q3 .... and so forth.
To account for multiple comparisons, I plan to use Bonferroni Correction.

Does my approach make sense, or can someone think of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A z-test requires the values to be numeric. Yours are not. So you need a different test to compare categorical variables. A test of proportions, where you would input the frequencies of successes (yes), in R you would achieve this with `prop.test()`. Also, Bonferroni correction is unecessary, Holm method is a better alternative (also called Bonferroni-Holm).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think z-tests can be used for testing proportions of categories. But the prop.test() function seems to implement a non-parametric test, which I prefer. https://www.r-bloggers.com/comparison-of-two-proportions-parametric-z-test-and-non-parametric-chi-squared-methods/